# Estimating 3D movement from Apple Watch

Tags: physics, signal-processing

I am trying to understand if there is a way to estimate 3D movement using the below variables along all three axis and relative to the orientation of the device:

- Attitude
- Acceleration
- Gravity
- Heading
- Rotation Rate

I have an Apple Watch, and I would like to understand if there is a way to estimate movement relevant to the earth. The problem is that the sensors data is orientated to the device. This is way over my understanding, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image: Apple Watch Orientation]

Comment: Theoretically, knowing that shape of an object, the acceleration and angular velocities of a given point of the object, it is possible to fully reconstruct its trajectory. However, in pratice it is not so trivial due to the noise of the sensors and also the fact that in most sensors gravity is also measured along. What you want to do is called "dead reckoning" in the literature. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Mick I would like to see the watch's movement relative to the Earth's axis (sorry if I am not using the correct terminology). If this was a car it would be easy  because a car's axis is the same as the earth's. But with a watch the axis is constantly changing depending on roll, pitch and yaw.

Comment: @Mick just read about dead reckoning, and I can understand that on a 2D level, and in relation to the earth, but transferring that to 3D and using the watch sensors I would not know where to start.

Comment: Does the Apple Watch have a GPS receiver?

Comment: You may want to watch this talk: [Sensor fusion on Android devices: a revolution in motion processing](https://youtu.be/C7JQ7Rpwn2k) (2010).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it does have a GPS receiver, but my intended application would require a higher resolution that what GPS can provide. And thanks for the link!

Comment: If you rely on inertial data alone, the uncertainty will grow too quickly. This is why fusing inertial data with GPS data is interesting. The term is [GPS/INS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS/INS). People often use Kalman filters for this. In the context of aviation, take a look at [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2619/15311).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I understand that, but then I would also be relying on the signal strength of the GPS, and also any indoor application would not work. At this point I am fine with uncertainty. Just trying to understand the math at this point.

Comment: You may want to look at [these](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=inertial).

Comment: Since this has been closed, consider posting the very same question at Signal Processing SE. This question is interesting. If you do so, please post the link here.